# Bing Maps v8, Rest Service URL for V8

Tags: rest, bing, bing-maps

I am working on Bing Maps V8. Now i already have V6 implemented. i need to upgrade to v8.

Currently the Rest Service URL being used for version v6 is :
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/query?key=BingMapsKey

I wanted to know for Bing Maps Version V8 is there any change/Different Rest Service URL or can i use the same ?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Shyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps REST service are their own API and independent of the web control versions. There is no change to the REST services. Note that Bing Maps V8 has two built in modules which you might consider using instead of the REST services;

- Search Module - a JavaScript library that wraps the REST location
  API.
  https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#searchByAddress+JS
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712846.aspx
- Autosuggest
  module - provides suggestions as you type. 
  https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#autoSuggestUi+JS
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712650.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!